# Unable to make a regex work in new Mac Big Sur terminal

Tags: macos, perl, character-encoding

I am trying to make a perl onliner work in mac Big Sur terminal. The online is this

```
perl -pi -e 's/REGULAR_EXPRESSION_TO_BE FOUND/REPLACEMENT/g' *.hmtl
```

When I try to search and replace in editor BBEDITOR it works fine, but when I try in macOS terminal it does not replace. I believe it may have to do with encoding since I am working with Spanish texts. But my texts are in UTF-8.

Comment: `*.hmtl` should probably be `*.html` ?

Comment: If your files use UTF-8, you need `-CD` among the options to tell perl that.

Comment: What are the local settings for your terminal?

Comment: Do you mean BBEdit?

Comment: Yes, I mean BBEdit? Best for now,

Comment: Brian I just checked and it had utf-8 as encoding by default.

Comment: Dear Shawn, I will immediately check your solution. Thnak you for generously sharing your knowledge with me.

Answer (score 2):

If your regex or replacement text are unicode, you need the `utf8` pragma to tell Perl to decode the command line script as unicode.  Otherwise they will be interpreted as bytes or otherwise according to your locale.  Just because it looks like the right character to you on your terminal doesn't mean it really is.  This is because the *terminal* does its *own* decoding of the bytes you pasted or typed or printed.

Add `-Mutf8` to the command line or do `use utf8`.  You can always use the `B::perlstring` function to see what Perl thinks of what you typed.

```
# v5.22
$ perl -e 'use B; print B::perlstring "愛"; '
"\346\204\233"

$ perl -Mutf8 -e 'use B; print B::perlstring "愛"; '
"\x{611b}"

$ perl -e 'print "\346\204\233"; '
愛
```

The regex and the file have to be in the same encoding for the matching to work.  Because obviously "\346\204\233" != "\x{611b}".  To remove the ambiguity of the terminal you might have to write a short script file to debug it.  You also might need `-CSD` as well.

See here for more information.

[perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun)
[utf8 pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/utf8)

HTH